# Hadoop Big Data File text search

Tags: hadoop, indexing, solr, full-text-search, bigdata

I am working on a Big Data project (cloudera environment) in which all data from multiple data sources are loaded in Hadoop. Now, I have a set of .pdf, .jpeg files that contain lots of texts. I want to search contents of these files against the data that is stored in HDFS. Can anyone tell me which library/framework I can use for my project..? I came to know about Apach Solr which seems interesting but wanted to know if there are any other tools out there that can be useful for my project.

Any feedback/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to search image processing framework and then get that data into solr. something like [this](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/indexing-and-searching-text-within-images-with-apache-solr/)

Comment: Thanks for your input!